# After training in AI Platform, where can I find model.bst or other model file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

I trained a XGBoost model using AI Platform [as here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/training-xgboost).

Now I have the choice in the Console to download the model, as follows (but not Deploy it, since "Only models trained with built-in algorithms can be deployed from this page"). So, I click to download.

[image]

However, in the bucket the only file I see is a tar, as follows.

[image]

That tar (directory tree follows) holds only  some training code, and *not* a  `model.bst`, `model.pkl`, or `model.joblib`,  or other such model file.

[image]

Where do I find `model.bst` or the like, [which I can deploy](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/getting-predictions-xgboost#create_a_model_resource)?

---

EDIT:

Following the answer, below, we see that the "Download model" button is misleading as it sends us to the job directory, not the output directory (which  is set arbitrarily  in [the code](http://%20https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/HEAD/xgboost/notebooks/census_training/train.py#L109)l the model is at `census_data_20210527_215945/model.bst` )

```
bucket = storage.Client().bucket(BUCKET_ID)
blob = bucket.blob('{}/{}'.format(
    datetime.datetime.now().strftime('census_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'),
    model))
blob.upload_from_filename(model)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only in-build algorithms automatically store the model in Google Cloud storage.

In your case, you have a custom training application.
You have to take care of saving the model on your own.

Referring to your example this is implemented as [listed here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/HEAD/xgboost/notebooks/census_training/train.py#L109).

The model is uploaded to Google Cloud Storage using the cloud storage client.

Comment: Thank you! We see that the "Download model" button is misleading as it sends us to the job directory, not the output directory (and in fact the GUI can't know where the model is, since hte model is saved to an arbitrary location).